# Angular5 @ Issue in Bundle.js

Tags: angular, webkit, angular5

Hi i have an issue while building my angular5 project in prod mode it is giving The Following Errors:

> ERROR in scripts.3c73d2a250157e743883.bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected character '@' [scripts.3c73d2a250157e743883.bundle.js:7,0]

While building in normal mode it will build properly while in production mode it shows errors.

Please Help Me To Solve The Issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Try opening the file to see exactly what's causing the error

Comment: the file not there in my system it will be produced after the sucessfull building i got the error so the file is not there

Answer (score 0):

I used to face same problem,

i did "ng build -prod"
it got solved for me so please try this and if not solved, 
check your cli version to latest and update in package.json too i hope this fix your problem thanks

for more reference you can check below link

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6013